# Insert Record into Table Join with LINQ-SQL ASP.NET MVC

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc, linq

Hi i would know how insert data into MsSQL DB using ASP.NET MVC.

I'm using (DBML) Entity with SQL-LINQ

I have 3 tables where 2 of them join with the first one

Table

**User**

id, name , surname , email

**Car**

id , id_User , model ,year

**Work**

id , id_User , location

I use this code to add a data into SQL

```
DataUserDataContext data = new DataUserDataContext(); 
User u = new User();
u.Name= "John";
u.Surname= "Lock";
u.email = "someemail@email.com" 
data.Users.InsertOnSubmit(u);
p.SubmitChanges();
```

Now My question is :

How could insert a new record considering that i should fill Car and Work table too?

Use the code before and take the ID (if i wasnt wrong there is a way to get the last entity)

Use this id to insert record into Car and Work Table

Is there a way to do this in a unique step?

Answer (score 0):

Don't think in terms of IDs but rather objects... put this code before SubmitChanges()...

```
u.Car = new Car() { model = 'honda', year = 2000 };
u.Work = new Work () { location = 'new york' };
```

Comment: i haven't u.Car but only u.Cars which is an EntitySet of User so i cant create a new Car()

Comment: I get the point but i cant associate my object with other one , so should be a problem of MVC 2 which miss this function?

Answer (score 0):

first you can also use this to insert your data to the users table like this

```
DataUserDataContext data = new DataUserDataContext(); 
User u = new User();
u.Name= "John";
u.Surname= "Lock";
u.email = "someemail@email.com" 
data.Users.AddObject(u)
data.SubmitChanges();
```

and you can get last inserted id from your Users table like this

```
var UserID=  (from con in dbdata.Users
     select con).Max(x => x.UserID);
```

and you can use to get last inserted id from users table

```
data.Users.OrderByDescending(u => u.UserId).FirstOrDefault()
```

and you can use this id to insert record from your car and work table like this

for Car table

```
DataUserDataContext data = new DataUserDataContext(); 
Car objcar = new Car()
objcar.id_User = UserID;
objcar.model="hondacity";
objcar.year="2012";
data.Cars.AddObject(objcar);
data.SubmitChanges();
```

for work table

```
DataUserDataContext data = new DataUserDataContext(); 
Work objwork=new Work();
objwork.id_User =UserID;
objwork.Location="US";
data.Works.AddObject(objwork);
data.SubmitChanges();
```

i think this will help you